# Diagonalization argument for indecidability of consistent theories

Tags: logic, computability

I am trying to understand the classical proof that no consistent, sufficiently strong, axiomatised formal theory is decidable. I have a hard time to grasp the diagonalization argument used in the proof

Comment: This is a very broad statement. Can you maybe articulate in more detail what difficulties you are having? What specific version of the proof are you looking at might also be helpful.

Comment: Are you talking about [the diagonal lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_lemma)?

Answer (score 1):

*I'm assuming you're talking about the [diagonal lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_lemma). For simplicity, I'm going to talk about the special case of PA.*

In my opinion, the diagonal lemma is poorly named (and I prefer calling it the "fixed point lemma"). This is because neither it nor its application in the proof of Godel's theorem are really - in my opinion at least - classical diagonalization.

Its role is the following:

- We start with the Godel numbering function $\ulcorner\cdot\urcorner:Sentences\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$. There are many such functions; our hope is that the one we've picked is "reasonable," in the sense that **basic properties of sentences wind up corresponding to definable properties of numbers**. See the last bulletpoint below.
- The goal of the fixed point lemma is to let us perform some measure of self reference: sentences of arithmetic refer directly only to numbers, but via Godel numbering we can interpret them (at least sometimes) as saying things about sentences; in light of this, it's at least plausible that we could somehow cook up a sentence which "talks about itself" in some way. **The fixed point lemma says that this is "maximally possible" - for any property $P$ of sentences whose "push-forward" under $\ulcorner\cdot\urcorner$ is definable in $\mathcal{N}$, we can express "This sentences has property $P$."** Put another way, the fixed point lemma says - *contra* the intuition one might reasonably develop from [the Liar paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liar_paradox) or similar - that self-reference is not inherently problematic; we've got a lot of it right here in arithmetic!

  - Note that **this immediately gives [Tarski's undefinability theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_undefinability_theorem)**: if the Godelization of the true theory of arithmetic, $\{\ulcorner\varphi\urcorner: \mathcal{N}\models\varphi\}$, were definable, then we could express "is the Godel number of a sentence which is false in $\mathcal{N}$" in the language of arithmetic; applying the fixed point lemma, [we would be able to write "This statement is false," leading to a contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liar_paradox).
  - Note also that we're really proving things about **the specific map $Sentences\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$** (that is, $\ulcorner\cdot\urcorner$) we've picked. Basically, a large part of the proof of Godel's theorem boils down to the statement, "There is a map $Sentences\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ with [special properties]." Any such map would do. Incidentally, we can use this perspective to rephrase Tarski's undefinability theorem in a perhaps-less-mysterious way: it says that for any map $\mu: Sentences\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$, *either* this map lacks certain nice properties *or* the set $\{\mu(\varphi):\mathbb{N}\models\varphi\}$ is not definable in the language of arithmetic.
  - The focus on the specific map is also worth pointing out since **this sort of statement makes sense in wide generality**: given a structure $\mathcal{M}$ *(here, the naturals)* and a theory $T$ true of $\mathcal{M}$ *(here, PA)*, we can talk about the relevant special properties which maps from sentences (in the language of $\mathcal{M}$) to $\mathcal{M}$ can possibly satisfy.
- OK, back to the topic. **Phrased precisely**, the fixed point lemma states that for any formula $\beta$ of one free variable, there is a sentence $\varphi$ such that PA proves $$\varphi\iff\beta(\ulcorner\varphi\urcorner).$$
- Now think back to the first bulletpoint. During our analysis of $\ulcorner\cdot\urcorner$, we show that "is provable" is definable; precisely, we show that the set $$\{\ulcorner\varphi\urcorner: PA\vdash\varphi\}$$ is definable in $\mathcal{N}$. Let $Prov$ be some formula defining this set. **We now apply the fixed point lemma to $\neg Prov$ get a sentence $\theta$ such that PA proves** $$\theta\iff \neg Prov(\theta).$$ Under [reasonable assumptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A9-consistent_theory) on PA, we can show that $\theta$ is independent of PA.

  - Note that these "reasonable assumptions" are actually a bit *stronger* than mere consistency. To show that we really only need consistency - and this is crucial for the strong form of the incompleteness theorem you mention, since that applies to theories *not* satisfying this stronger condition - we use [a trick due to Rosser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosser%27s_trick). But the logical structure of the argument is the same.

---

Hopefully this shows **how the fixed point lemma is used** in Godel's theorem. There are of course a few gaps in the above outline. The one which is relevant here is:

> How do we prove the fixed point lemma?

Unfortunately, the proof of the fixed point lemma - while short - is generally considered fairly unintuitive (just as with its computational analogue, the [recursion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_recursion_theorem#Kleene's_second_recursion_theorem)). Personally, I think working carefully through [Wikipedia's writeup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_lemma#Proof) is a good way to learn it. But before you do so, I think it's better to understand the outline I've written above - you don't have to be confident that each piece works yet, but I think it is a good idea to internalize the overall strategy before diving into the specifics of the fixed point lemma.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your clarification is very helpful!

Comment: @GeorgeChailos I've added a bit of flavor. Let me know if you have any additional questions.